# How to select and SUM seven high score marks between nine marks on single row

Tags: php, mysql

Helo every one! I tried to find solution on the previous asked questions from the site but I find none of them related with mine, I need help on how to select seven scored marks between nine on the same row in a table which have HIGH SCORE and SUM them as shown below.

```
name   | math | geography | history | pds | ict | civics | social | vskil |  french

Joseph   100    90          80        84    70    40       70       90        70
```

So here the following seven (7) marks supposed to be chosen (100 + 90 + 80 + 84 + 70 + 90 + 70).

Any help please.

Comment: your table structure is incorrect. Subjects, Marks should be in rows and not columns

Comment: How should it suppose to be structured. please can you show me example

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert columns into rows and then make your select

You can try this query

```
select sum(grade) from (
(select math as 'grade' from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select geography from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select history from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select pds from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select ict from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select civics from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select social from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select vskil from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
union all
(select french from table1 where name = 'Joseph')
) as x
order by grade desc
limit 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get better performance, use less storage and make code easier to write with the following table structure instead of the current one.

Table students:

```
id integer primary key
name varchar
```

Table subjects

```
studentid integer primary key references students(id)
subject varchar
marks int
```

Real optimation would mean a subjects table and a subject marks table. Please read up on database normalization for details.

With this structure for a given student,

```
SELECT SUM(marks) 
FROM (SELECT marks FROM subjects WHERE studentid=some_number ORDER BY marks DESC limit 7) AS a
```

Gives the marks for the top 7 subjets for a given student.

Comment: Thank you for that, I should try to use such approach, because Until now the problem still there, I tried bellow query but it just sum all 9 results instead of  seven.

Comment: great. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I must say thank you to you guys, below  "developer" query run and provide desired answer after change the structure. Thank you a lot. this site is so help fully